# MySQL: match period character at the end of string sing REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm writing a (fairly basic) search tool and I'm using this regex to match against search queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]'
```

I'm searching against a column of bandnames, one of which is in the system as "D.O.A.". A search for `d.o.a.` (in either case) returns no matches, but a search for `d.o.a` (note: no final trailing period) returns the correct match. Is there a simple tweak I can make to this regex which will return the correct rows, or should I start again with another one?

EDIT: by request, here's the actual search being used:

```
SELECT * FROM bands WHERE band_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]d.o.a.[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste the right regex?

Comment: Hah, yes, I wanted to keep it generic. Will update, one sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. **A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_)**.

(Emphasis Mine)

A period `.` is NOT a word character, so you cannot match the end of a word after it.  Unfortunately there's no simple way to fix your regular expression, unless you can tell us EXACTLY what you consider a word boundary.  If it's whitespace, something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[[:space:]]foo[[:space:]]'
```

Will work.  Or, if I'm reading the spec correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[[:space:][:punct:]]foo[[:space:][:punct:]]'
```

Will use spaces and punctuation.  Though

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]_]foo[^[:alnum:]_]'
```

is probably the closest you're going to get.

EDIT:  Realizing just now that you're also going to be trying to match against the beginning or end of your column as well:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '(^|[^[:alnum:]_])foo([^[:alnum:]_]|$)'
```

will check against the beginning of the string (^) and the end ($) as well.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer -- none of those three regexes return anything for `d.o.a.` though! I hadn't read the spec (I know, I know...) so that does help. Lazy as it may seem I'm tempted just to trim trailing periods from the query, as this will match and I'm not precious about the final dot.

Comment: Well, Is d.o.a at the end of the text field?  Or the beginning?

Comment: It *is* the text field. Well, the row contains `D.O.A.`.

Comment: Wait, then why are you using regular expressions?  Why not `=` ?

Comment: If you're using regular expressions just for a case-insensitive match, you're killing yourself for no reason.  Try `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(field) = 'foo'`

Comment: @MattAndrews No... don't go away!  Regexp isn't [Sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)!

Comment: I... I started typing a reply here about this being a fuzzy site search, but I can't remember why I made it a regex to start with. I guess to avoid case problems, but that doesn't really make sense... hm..

Comment: Oh, and your updated solution works for a query of `d.o.a.` and also `d.o.a`. Thanks!

Comment: Oh: remembered why I use a regex: this is a search of half a dozen tables, and not all of them are single-string columns: the same search also searches news article headlines, so I want it to match "Green Day" in a string of "Green Day announce new album". I could probably avoid the regex for the band table, which just has band names, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the . when using REGEXP.  Use \. instead of .
The . character is for matching any single character.
Corrected version:

```
   SELECT * FROM bands WHERE band_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]d\.o\.a\.[[:>:]]'
```